# PHP while loop is returning only one value

Tags: php, html, arrays, while-loop, return

I know that are several questions similar to this one, and i have looked at them, but still i haven't managed to modify my function in order to work.

So i have this function getCar_2(); in functions.php page. The thing is that it should display more cars, because i have more cars in the database, but it displays only the last one. Same with getCar_1(), the two functions are the same.

Here is the function:

```
<?php
function getCar_2(){
global $connect;

$text = "";

$get_car_2 = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE category_id=5";
$get_car_result_2 = mysqli_query($connect, $get_car_2) or die(mysqli_query());

while($row_car_2 = mysqli_fetch_array($get_car_result_2)){
    $car_model_2 = $row_car_2['car_name'];
    $car_image_2 = $row_car_2['car_image'];

    if(isset($car_model_2) && isset($car_image_2)){
        $text =  "
            <div id='' style='white-space:nowrap;'>
            <p id='model' style='display:inline-block; margin-right:10px; margin-left:10px; padding-top:10px; position:relative; bottom:35px;'>$car_model_2</p></a> 
            <img src='administrator/images/$car_image_2' width='120' height='80' style='display: inline-block; box-shadow: 0 0 11px #000;'/><br>
            </div>";
        }
    }
    return $text;
}
?>
```

and is displayed on another page like this:

```
<?php
$car_1 = getCar_1();
$car_2 = getCar_2();
if(!empty($car_1) || !empty($car_2)){
?>

<div class="block">
    <div class="up">
        <div class="title"><h4>Cars</h4></div>
    </div>
    <div class="down">
        <div class="column_1"><b><?php echo $car_1; ?></b></div>
        <div class="column_2"><b><?php echo $car_2; ?></b></div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: looking to your code should return empty string or the first car with  isset($car_model_2) && isset($car_image_2)   ... remove the return inside the loop ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not concatenating your `text` variable, so on each loop pass it will contain only the last value. You should use concatenation operator `.=` instead of assignment operator `=`

```
$text .= "
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the previous row values before they are used. Looks like you want to append new row results to the prior one, for that.. just need to add one line and one period...

```
$text =''; //define $text so you can append to it

if(isset($car_model_2) && isset($car_image_2)){

    $text .=  "
    <div id='' style='white-space:nowrap;'>
   ......
```

Notice the `.=`  to append the new result to the previous row.
Appending variables this way is called concatenation.

Periods are also used to concatenate strings and variables for printing.
Like . . .

```
echo '<div class="column_1"><b>'. $car_1.'</b></div>';
```

Comment: Thanks, i feel kinda silly now after trying for hours to resolve this, not knowing that a single dot could solved the issue.